# Is MultiTasking affects the bettery life

Tags: android, iphone, multitasking

I had read the document about multitasking. i comes to know that iphone and ipad does not support multitasking because Multitasking affects the Battery Life.
Its is true? or if is it true then ...

```
How MultiTasking Affects the Bettery Life?
```

Comment: you may read : http://www.loopinsight.com/2010/05/19/google-says-multitasking-apps-hurt-androids-battery-life/

Comment: In 2015.. *outdated articles, sigh*

Comment: Using the CPU uses battery. The more CPU (or CPU cores, and of what type, as the case is these days) uses more battery. There is some inherent overhead with 'multitasking', but additional power consumption is largely correlated with additional processing power used.. *work takes energy*.

Answer (score 1):

For sure multitasking will drain you battery much faster..
Why??-

Every multitasking task need to be synchronized, so you need to use mutex, semaphore, conditional variables, and need to schedule the task all these things need processing and scheduling, system calls which needs continuous processing,  and do these processing you need power and power will drain your battery.

But, tradeoff of between battery life and performance should be critically analyzed!!! Some it will be better to do lots of process which your screen is active because if it takes more time to process then your screen will be active and consuming a lot of battery!!!

Here is an article which talks about Larry Page and Steve Jobs statement over multitasking and battery life:

http://www.loopinsight.com/2010/05/19/google-says-multitasking-apps-hurt-androids-battery-life/

http://www.techradar.com/us/news/phone-and-communications/mobile-phones/larry-page-your-android-battery-life-should-last-a-day-690439

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: The synchronization itself is *not* a power draw (and can be considered to use effectively use no CPU) - actual *work* on the CPUs is what is. Multitasking applications may do more work - because they can (and there is a benefit to such), or because they incorrectly think they need to - but this is work applied to a task and is not related to the 'synchronizing overhead'. A sleeping task (eg. blocking on a semaphore) is *not* a significant power draw itself.